# Can't change checkstyle configuration in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, size, line, checkstyle

Checkstyle LineLength warning does never disappear, even after changing my conf file. I tested every possibility but the bug still keeps alive. I tried external file, internal file, remote file.

This is my default configuration for Checkstyle:

[image]

This is my file content:

[image]

And this is the Checkstyle warning:
[image]

It looks like eclipse keeps the first default conf (google conf) and never changes that. I also tried mvn site with checkstyle reporting based on my url file: The warning disappears in the reporting page, but it does not in eclipse.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted:

- project from eclipse
- eclipse file and folder in the project directory (.settings, .checkstyle, .classspath, .project)

Then I re-import it as a maven project and now all is right :)